# Asking for input of integers, into a list of int (no arrays allowed)

Tags: java, list, input, integer

How would I take a list of integers inputted by the user, in one method, and be able to call on that method and calculate the max and min value, as well as the average, in separate methods?

The problem is to: Asks the user to enter the number of students in a class. Using a loop, write a program that takes the exam grades of all the students entered one by one. 
Create a menu to display the following options:
1. Minimum grade
2. max grade.
3. average.
etc

NO ARRAYS ALLOWED
USE SEPARATE METHODS

> import java.util.Scanner;
>   public class hw07_emena 
>   {

```
public static double gradeEnter(double sum, double min, double max)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the amount of students in a class: ");
    int amtStudents = keyboard.nextInt();

    int i=0;
    sum=0;
    if(i<amtStudents)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the grade for student " + (i+1));
        double stGrade = keyboard.nextDouble();
        sum = sum+stGrade;
        i++;

        return sum;
    }




}


/*public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of students in a class: ");
    int amtStudents = keyboard.nextInt();


    double sum = 0;
    int i=0;
    while(i<=amtStudents)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the grade of student " + (i+1));
        double stGrade = keyboard.nextDouble();
        i++;



        double minGrade = 9999;
        double maxGrade = -9999;



        double classAvg = 0;

            if(i==amtStudents)
            {

                System.out.println("");
            }
    }




}
*/
```

}

Comment: No arrays allowed? So is an ArrayList allowed? What about List? Map? ???

Comment: @DonLarynx The title explicitly specifies that a `List<>` should be used.

Comment: No arrays or array list, unfortunatly. List is allowed, and I am not sure what map is but Im sure it is allowed. This is what I have so far:

Comment: @MintyFresh: Yes, although I need to verify this for reasons: See above comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numStudents = sc.nextInt();
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numStudents; i++){
        int grade = sc.nextInt();
        max = Math.max(max, grade);
        min = Math.min(min, grade);
        total += grade;
    }
    double average = total/numStudents;
    //Your menu will be specific to you. It will need to go here and return 
    //average, min, or max

}
```

You don't need to store the grades, just the results.

Comment: Thank you, this is actually much easier than seperate methods.